# Angular Js Ui Routing 404 with language preserved

Tags: angularjs, routes, internationalization, http-status-code-404, angular-ui-router

I am currently building an international app, and the plan has been for the language to be the first part of the url.  So most of my routes have urls like "/{lang}/home", or "/{lang}/product/{id}" in them.

I understand that my otherwise can't possibly try to figure out a state variable like language because someone could go to my site by munging the url after the domain etc.  So my otherwise puts them down to /en/404.  I was hoping however that if for example, the user makes some typo mistake like "/es/hom" that I could recognize that they provided a language code, but I can't figure out routing beyond that and thus send them to /es/404.

The following is my stab at it in the route configuration, but it isn't working well.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/en/404');//if url is impossible then we put them in english 404
$urlRouterProvider.when("/{lang}/*", "/{lang}/404");//attempt to get to lang/404 if we can discern language
$urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/en/home');//if they just land at the site then en/home
```

As this is going right now, I always land on /en/404 if my url is invalid.  That doesn't surprise me, but I was really hoping I could get that first when statement to be clever enough that if the user were to browse to mysite.com/es/hom  that it would at least recognize that they are trying to use spanish and thus send them to /es/404.

Comment: Couldn't you have a list of acceptable 'lang's and just have that route see if the provided url has a lang that is a part of that set?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/:lang', {
    templateUrl: 'lang.html',
    controller: 'languageCtrl'
  }).otherwise('/:lang/404.html')};
 });
```